# Why does my google chart look wrong

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

So I'm trying to display some stats by minute, but the charts..it looks wrong, or am I wrong?
[image]

I have a jsfiddle example HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/p0j5qfL9/1/

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(load_page_data);

function load_page_data(zoom,action,time,entry_id){

    zoom = typeof zoom !== 'undefined' ? zoom : 'date';
    action = typeof action !== 'undefined' ? action : 'banner view';
    time = typeof time !== 'undefined' ? time : $('.actions_logs .sort_time').val();
    entry_id = typeof entry_id !== 'undefined' ? entry_id : '';
    rows = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: "/stats/get-stats",
        data: {zoom : zoom, action : action, time: time, entry_id : entry_id},
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(json, function( index, value ) {
                    date = new Date(value.created);
                    rows.push([new Date(value.created),parseInt(value.total)]);
                });

                drawBasic(rows,action,zoom);
            }
        }
    });
}

function drawBasic(rows,action,zoom) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(rows);
    column_type = (zoom == 'minute' || zoom == 'hour') ? 'datetime' : 'date';
    data.addColumn(column_type, 'Time of Day');
    data.addColumn('number', action);


    data.addRows(rows);

    var options = {
        title: 'Action',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Time',
            format: (column_type == 'datetime') ? 'yyyy/M/d HH:mm' : null
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Hits'
        },
        pointSize: 5,
        legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'end' },
        animation: {"startup": true}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    $('.loading-chart').remove();
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not sorted in any order, so the lines will just zip back and forth depending on the date.

Sorting by the data date after having added them all will return what I *think* you are after.

```
rows.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
```

Line 19 of this fiddle ->
<s>https://jsfiddle.net/p0j5qfL9/1/</s> https://jsfiddle.net/p0j5qfL9/3/

EDIT: Whoops, wrong link.

Answer (score 0):

As varbrad said, you should sort your array of data. The points are showed according with the sequence of your array.